# Looking for a way to increase my USB current, would a powered USB hub do the trick?

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-hub

All ports on my computer are only capable of 1A current and a USB hub I'm considering claims to be capable of 3A downstream in the C port.

The hub comes with an optional power supply and the store claims that the hub current is source dependant and that they think connecting it to the power supply won't change the current. (Meaning the C port will not supply 3A but only 1A like my computer currently does)

Do you think that's true? If so, what would be the advantage of using the optional power supply? And what would be the best way to get more current (At least 2A) from a C port?

Comment: What model hub.  I am talking a bit beyond my expertise here, but what they say could certainly be true.  As I understand it a 3 amp 5v connection requires different (lower) pullup resistance is required.  If the hub does not implement this, it wont provide more then 1.5 amps. It could still be useful to power multiple devices which draw say 1 amp of power each from a single usb port which can only provide 1 amp of power.

Comment: It's the ST-U-1470 https://www.netbitct.co.il/shop/brands/st-lab/st-lab-usb-hub/st-u-1470/

Comment: I couldn't find any more info on this hub but it's the only hub I could find whoch claoms to supply 3A and has a C port